# How to use CAS-SSO if disable cookie

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I want to know if CAS-SSO is currently capable of functioning without cookies enabled. For example, on the Mobile App. 
Is there any solutions to fix this problem? 
I am using the following releases:

CAS Server 4.2.7
CAS Client 3.3.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure. You can enable the Rest communication of it.

Click [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html) to see the CAS Rest protocol documentation.

You will need to manager the tickets (TGT and ST) by your application.

I hope it can help you.